# React native text issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was just creating app calculate user amount with some and display into text.Issue I facing when user amount is too long the result in the text splits like for example result amount is like  Rs 7004505400089090760
it display in Text like Rs 70
                        045054000890760 splits amount like this i have to show in single in react native.guys pls help me. I have tried PixelRatio also if there is any possible to reduce size dynamically in react native?

Answer (score 0):

The most sophisticated approach in case of amount would be to round this off for user experience and from the perspective of shortening it , you would have to reduce the font size of the text and one more way to cut the text in an elegant manner would be using http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/text.html#ellipsizemode

this would just add '...' in place to let user know that text is truncated due to space.

Comment: Thnks have another doubt I how to check user enter number with two decimal places and have to disable copy paste option in react native. I have seen one npm the name is called NumTextInput they restrict using copy an paste option but allowing three decimal points .if there is any other way. What exactly I want means user enters amount that will calculate result and show.Check if user enter more tahn two decimal poit like 90.90.87 have to disable to type.I have tried event.preventDefault() using regular expression. its showing syntheticEvent perfoemance issue.

Comment: So , all i assume is that you want an user to restrict to some constraints , you can bind value prop of TextInput to the component state and assign a callback onChangeText to your function and change accordingly , 
<TextInput value ={this.state.value} onChangeText={() => {
// conditions here 
this.setState({with value you want to show in textinput}) 
} 
/> 

this should work